# How to XOR two hex strings so that each byte is XORed separately?

Tags: python, string, hex, encode, xor

I have been posting similar questions here for a couple of days now, but it seems like I was not asking the right thing, so excuse me if I have exhausted you with my XOR questions :D.

To the point - I have two hex strings and I want to XOR these strings such that each byte is XORed separately (i.e. each pair of numbers is XORed separately). And I want to do this in python, and I want to be able to have strings of different lengths. I will do an example manually to illustrate my point (I used the code environment because it allows me to put in spaces where I want them to be):

```
Input:
s1 = "48656c6c6f"
s2 = "61736b"

Encoding in binary:
48 65 6c 6c 6f = 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
61 73 6b       = 01100001 01110011 01101011

XORing the strings:
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
                  01100001 01110011 01101011
                  00001101 00011111 00000100

Converting the result to hex:
00001101 00011111 00000100 = 0d 1f 04

Output:
0d1f04
```

So, to summarize, I want to be able to input two hex strings (these will usually be ASCII letters encoded in hex) of different or equal length, and get their XOR such that each byte is XORed separately.

Comment: Why not cycle the `s2` key and apply it to *all* characters of `s1`? Why only apply it to the last 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`binascii.unhexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) to turn your hex strings to binary data, then XOR that, going back to hex with [`binascii.hexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify, hexlify
>>> s1 = "48656c6c6f"
>>> s2 = "61736b"
>>> hexlify(''.join(chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for c1, c2 in zip(unhexlify(s1[-len(s2):]), unhexlify(s2))))
'0d1f04'
```

The actual XOR is applied per byte of the decoded data (using `ord()` and `chr()` to go to and from integers).

Note that like in your example, I truncated `s1` to be the same length as `s2` (ignoring characters from the start of `s1`). You can encode *all* of `s1` with a shorter key `s2` by cycling the bytes:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> hexlify(''.join(chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for c1, c2 in zip(unhexlify(s1), cycle(unhexlify(s2)))))
'2916070d1c'
```

You don't *have* to use `unhexlify()`, but it is a lot easier than looping over `s1` and `s2` 2 characters at a time and using `int(twocharacters, 16)` to turn that into integer values for XOR operations.

The Python 3 version of the above is a little lighter; use `bytes()` instead of `str.join()` and you can drop the `chr()` and `ord()` calls as you get to iterate over integers directly:

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify, hexlify
>>> s1 = "48656c6c6f"
>>> s2 = "61736b"
>>> hexlify(bytes(c1 ^ c2 for c1, c2 in zip(unhexlify(s1[-len(s2):]), unhexlify(s2)))) 
b'0d1f04'
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> hexlify(bytes(c1 ^ c2 for c1, c2 in zip(unhexlify(s1), cycle(unhexlify(s2)))))
b'2916070d1c'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What I don't understand, is this part:

for c1, c2 in zip(unhexlify(s1), cycle(unhexlify(s2)))))

The thing is, I am new to python and get easily confused. I think the zip function has something to do with arrays, but I don't know how those work in Python. Besides, I thought for loops only have one counter, but in here you have two - c1 and c2, which also confuses me.

Comment: `zip()` takes multiple input sequences, and pairs up their elements. So it gives you a sequence of `[(s1[0], s2[0]), (s1[1], s2[1]), ...]` with each tuple formed by taking elements from each input sequence at that same index.

Comment: @NorsulRonsul: Because in this case `zip()` has two input lists, each output element is a tuple with two values. The `for` loop unpacks those into two value (just like you can do tuple unpacking in regular assignment, `foo, bar = ('spam', 'eggs')` assigns `foo = 'spam'` and `bar = 'eggs'`.

Comment: I see now, but I have another problem now :D. I don't understand what did you do in the second part. What does it mean to encode all of s1? and what does it mean to cycle bytes?

Comment: @NorsulRonsul: Instead of just encoding just 3 characters (`'llo'` of `'Hello'`) with the 3 characters of your key (`ask`), we encode *all* of `Hello` by reusing the key, starting from the start again when you reach the end; `H` with `a`, `e` with `s`, `l` with `k`, then cycle to the start again and encode `l` with `a`, and `o` with `s`. The `itertools.cycle()` method lets us implement cycling over `s2` with just one function.

Comment: Answer accepted! I'm new here, so I didn't know how this all works :D

Answer (score 6):

I found a very simple solution:

```
def xor_str(a,b):
    result = int(a, 16) ^ int(b, 16) # convert to integers and xor them
    return '{:x}'.format(result)     # convert back to hexadecimal
```

It will xor the string until one of theme ends

Comment: It always bugs me when people don't use builtin format. `return format(result, 'x')`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what are you exactly searching for, but hopefully this be useful for you.

```
>>> def getstr(encoded):
     return "".join([chr(int(i+k, 16))for (i,k) in zip(encoded[0::2], encoded[1::2])])

>>> getstr(s1)
'Hello'

>>> getstr(s2)
'ask'
```

Starting with two normal strings, you can find your results doing something like this:

```
>>> "".join(reversed(["%02X" % (ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for c1, c2 in zip(reversed(getstr(s1)),       reversed(getstr(s2)))]))
'0D1F04'
```